# Obtener elementos de listas en python

Tags: html, python, json

Una duda, mi intención con este código, es obtener los elementos que tienen las listas que se observan en el código cuando se hace print(type(key)), sin embargo, noto que las listas están en una variable ([image: [1]]), es decir, cuando accedo a la variable "key" se muestran múltiples listas y mi intención es acceder a los elementos de cada lista. ¿Tienen idea de como hacerlo? Por ejemplo lo que quiero obtener es:
print(key[0][0])

'148'

Pero en vez de eso, obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\SEL\Prueba_(SED)\Prueba\lista.json") as contenido:
    
    archi = json.load(contenido)
    
    for arch in archi['limpieza']:

       for arc in arch['hoja']:

           key = list(arc.values())
            [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
           print(type(key))
```

El archivo de donde se sacan las listas es un JSON

```
{
"limpieza":[
    {"hoja":[
        {"precio":"148","producto":"Cloro"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Salvo"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Maestro Limpio"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Blanqueador"},
        {"precio":"","producto":""}
    ]},
    {"hoja":[
        {"precio":"148","producto":"Desinfectante"},
        {"precio":"178","producto":"Jabon"},
        {"precio":"225","producto":"Pino"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Cepillo"},
        {"precio":"208","producto":"Escoba"}
    ]},
    {"hoja":[
        {"precio":"2","producto":"Recogedor"},
        {"precio":"148","producto":"Bolsas para la basura"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Cesto de basura"},
        {"precio":"79","producto":"Jergas"},
        {"precio":"","producto":""}
    ]}
]
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se como arreglar la pregunta porque no entiendo que querias mostrar en cada caso.... por favor, pone las imagenes donde realmente queres...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando `json.load()` lee un archivo con información json, lo que hace es cargar en memoria un diccionario con los datos:

```py
>>> import json
>>> with open(r"la/ruta/de/lista.json") as contenido:
...     archi = json.load(contenido)
...
>>> type(archi)
<class 'dict'>
>>> archi
{'limpieza': [{'hoja': [{'precio': '148', 'producto': 'Cloro'}, {'precio': '79'...
```

Como ya tienes un diccionario, puedes acceder a una posición específica, colocando los identificadores correspondientes hasta llegar al nivel deseado:

```
>>> archi['limpieza'][0]['hoja'][0]['precio']
'148'
>>> archi['limpieza'][1]['hoja'][3]['producto']
'Cepillo'
```

Si, por ejemplo, quieres listar todos los elementos. Cambia la ruta de dónde está el archivo json.

```py
import json

with open(r"la/ruta/de/lista.json") as contenido:
    archi = json.load(contenido)
    for numHoja, elem in enumerate(archi['limpieza']):
        print('Hoja #', numHoja+1)
        for nItem, item in enumerate(elem['hoja']):
            if not item['producto']:
                continue # <-- Si producto está en blanco
            print(f'{nItem+1:<2} ${item["precio"]:<5} {item["producto"]}')
        print()
```

Resultado

```
Hoja # 1
1  $148   Cloro
2  $79    Salvo
3  $79    Maestro Limpio
4  $79    Blanqueador

Hoja # 2
1  $148   Desinfectante
2  $178   Jabon
... etc
```